# Binding to Draggabilly events in Coffeescript

Tags: drag-and-drop, coffeescript

I'm using packery and draggabilly to enable DnD in my app. I have DnD working, but I need to bind to the 'dragEnd' event, but my handler is not being called.

Here is my code:

```
els = packery.getItemElements()

    for elem in els
      draggable = new Draggabilly( elem )
      packery.bindDraggabillyEvents( draggable )
      $(draggable).on 'dragEnd', (e) ->
        console.log e
```

Am I binding to the correct element? Should it be the Draggabilly element? I've tried using. draggable.element and elem, but the handler is never called. Still new to Cofffescript, so any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I need not cast the 'draggable' as a jQuery object. The line where I bind the draggable should read:

```
 draggable.on 'dragEnd', (e) ->
```